# Class with static linkage

Tags: class, c++11, static

If I recall correctly, static linkage means that a variable or function is local to its compilation unit. Meaning that there could be variables or functions with the same name and parameters in other compilation units.

I want this for a class.

Let's say I have multiple compilation units that need to ensure proper deletion at exit. So I use atexit handlers. But every compilation unit should put its own atexit-handler into place.
I did this by making a class like this:

```
class Init {
private:
    static Init* self;

    Init() {
        std::atexit(Init::cleanup);
    }

    static void cleanup() {
        // Do cleanup
    }
};
Init* Init::self = new Init;
```

But if I have multiple classes called `Init` in various CUs the linker gets confused. And the compiler won't let me do `static class Init {...}`.

How do I archive my cleanup (if possible with classes that are called `Init`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your class into an unnamed namespace.

Then, although types don't have linkage, the same effect is borne.

```
// Everything inside here is unique to this TU
namespace {
   class Init { /** whatever **/ };
   Init* Init::self = new Init;
}

int main()
{
   // "Init" in here will refer to that which you created above
}
```

Comment: @MartinB.: No rush. Someone else might come along with a better idea, even.